# WPF: How do you print in Landscape mode?

Tags: wpf, printing, landscape

found [this function](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/printing-in-wpf) online, which works great... except I can't figure out how to default it to print in landscape.

```
private void PrintClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
  if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
  { dialog.PrintVisual(_PrintCanvas, "My Canvas"); }
}
```

How does one actually set the default to print my wpf content to landscape mode?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit:** Fixed variable name, mentioned by @SHIN JaeGuk

```
private void PrintClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    { 
        //Set PageOrientation to Landscape
        dialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        dialog.PrintVisual(_PrintCanvas, "My Canvas"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Original Answer**
This has already been answered:
[Setting PageOrientation for the Wpf DocumentViewer PrintDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003585/setting-pageorientation-for-the-wpf-documentviewer-printdialog)

**End Original Answer**

**Edit:**

It appears there is a problem with the PrintTicket and printing visuals, check out:
[Same question on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/56fb78b1-efc2-4ff7-aa2c-73c198a790b4)

The original poster on the MSDN forum posted on the last post that the work around they used was to basically capture the visual and convert to xps document for printing, this will allow the usage of PrintTicket to set the orientation of the printed document.

Comment: I'm not looking at printing a Document, but a piece of content. For example, right now I pass in `(Visual)mytabs.SelectedContent` into my `print.printVisual()` method. Where exactly would I stick my `mytabs.SelectedContent` in the answer you pointed to?

Answer (score 2):

```
private void PrintClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
   if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
      { 
         dialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation=System.Printing.PageOrientation.Landscape;
         dialog.PrintVisual(this, "First LandScape"); 
      }
 }
```

You need to add a reference to ReachFramework.dll and System.Printing.dll each.