# Set Print Orientation on PrintDialog using Flow Document

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument, printdialog

Just wondering if there is a way to set the print document orientation on a Print Dialog that is using a flow document.

e.g.

```
var document = userControl.Content as FlowDocument;
var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    var paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource) document).DocumentPaginator;
    paginator.PageSize = new Size(userControl.Width, userControl.Height);

    //Set Orientation Landscape .....


    printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, PrintDescription);
}
```

Comment: Already answered 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003585/setting-pageorientation-for-the-wpf-documentviewer-printdialog

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
printDialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = System.Printing.PageOrientation.Landscape;
```

You need to add a reference to `ReachFramework.dll` and `System.Printing.dll` each.